# BGE: where to place external python modules when exporting for Mac OS X

Tags: scripting, game-engine, export, add-on, osx

Say that I am developing a game on Mac OS X, and I want to export it as a runtime (for Mac OS X). 
I can use the "Save as Game Engine runtime" plug-in. 
This does not take into account my external scripts (I use python controllers in module mode).
Say that I have all the scripts in a "scripts" folder and I am using Monster's LinkedPythonFolder ([link](https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?285724-Python-Folder-Linking-very-easy-access-to-your-python-folders)), or any other method, to make Blender aware of this.

Where should I place the "scripts" folder once I've created the runtime "myGame.app"? 
The only place that seems to work is the "Resources" folder inside the "myGame.app" package. I don't understand why. Is this because this is the directory where the exporter puts the "game.blend" file? (this is actually the myGame.blend file which is renamed by the exporter. Why does it need to rename that?. Isn't there any other directory that is in the Python search path? What about the folder where the "myGame.app" resides?

[image: This folder structure works fine even without LinkedPythonFolder]

Comment: I can't help on MacOS directly. But I guess the files should be relative to the start-up blend file. As "save as runtime" binds the blend file to the blenderplayer I think it should be relative to the app file. This might be different in MacOS than in WinOS and Linux. I really do not know.

Comment: What do you mean by start-up blend file? If you mean the .app generated by the exporter, placing the "scripts" folder in the same directory won't work. In this sense, the LinkedPythonFolder technique becomes useless. The only thing that works is placing the "scripts" folder inside the "Resources" within the generated .app package. And in case you do that, you don't need the LinkedPythonFolder anymore.

Comment: The start-up blend file is the blend file that gets loaded at game start. It can refer to any other blend file. These references are either absolute (good for development) or relative (good for publishing). Python modules are expected within the Python search path. The Python search path of your game includes your default Python search path (Python installation), the location of your start-up blend file and the location of referred blend files. It the referred blend file is not found - the python search path can't include them.

Comment: The location of my start-up .blend file is the "Resources" folder within the generated .app package. The scripts reside inside a "scripts" folder within the same location (e.g.: //game.app/Contents/Resources/scripts/script.py). Like this, the game works. Does this mean that the subfolders included in the location of my start-up .blend file (like the "scripts" folder) are in the Python search path as well?

Comment: From my experience folders with linked blend files are added to the Python search path. That is what LinkedPythonFolder.blend is doing. When you link anything from it (it does not matter what) the folder it resides in gets included. But I have WinOS only. So I can't tell the structure on MacOS. I suggest to print the Python search path to the console for investigation.

Comment: import sys;[print(p) for p in sys.path]

Comment: I think I understand how the LinkedPythonFolder.blend works. And it works like a charme as far as the game is not exported. However, when I export the game my scripts are not included, ad I have to include them manually. The only folder which seems to be included in the python search path seems to be te Resources folder. I don't really care about other system folders which are not inside the .app file. In this sense, the LinkedPythonFolder.blend becomes useless.

Comment: Either you include the LinkedPythonFolder.blend or not the game will only work if the scripts reside in the Resources folder or any subfolder.

Comment: I did my investigations on WinOS. That folders of linked blend files are added to the Python Search path might be a side effect of linking which does not work at other platforms. An alternative way is https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?196543.

Comment: Thank you. I already knew about this other method, my investigation was mostly for better understanding. Last question: when you export for Windows OS is the script folder exported as well or you need to copy it manually?

Comment: The add-ons bind the start-up blend with the blender player forming a separate application file. This file and the necessary libraries are copied. As far as I know nothing else. Therefore you need to copy all other files (blend files, textures etc.) manually. Finally you get your current directory plus the application file (which makes the start-up blend obsolete).