# python controller module code works inside blender but not saved as game engine runitime

Tags: python, scripting, game-engine

I try to run a simple python invisible visible toggling python controller module. This works well inside blender, but not in the generated game engine runtime.

I have:

- a 'Cube' mesh
- a keyboard sensor named 'VisibilityKey' with 'All Keys' selected
- a python controller in 'Module' mode with source 'mybpylib.visibilitytoggle'
- controller and sensor are linked.

In the mybpylib.py file i have the following code:

```
def visibilitytoggle(o_ctrlr):
    if (o_ctrlr.sensors["VisibilityKey"].positive):
        for _ in o_ctrlr.sensors["VisibilityKey"].events:
            if (o_ctrlr.owner.visible == True):
                o_ctrlr.owner.visible = False
                print("i was visible")
            else:
                o_ctrlr.owner.visible = True
                print("i was invisible")
```

When I inside blender game engine press 'P' the invisible visibile  toggling of the cube woks perfectly by pressing any key.

When I 'File / Save As Game Engine Runtime' 
the game get saved, but when I start the executable the invisible visible toggling does not work.

I am using:

- Blender version 2.78c (and corresponding blenderplayer)
- on MacOS X 10.12.5 (sierra)

I am still quit a blender noob.
It might be that I miss something simple but I can not figure out what.
Any help is appreciated.

Elmar

Comment: I think that you dont need the loop ´´for _ in o_ctrlr.sensors["VisibilityKey"].events:´´

[https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?213658-Exporting-a-game-on-mac] (https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?213658-Exporting-a-game-on-mac)

Comment: @Strapicarus : you might be right. it would work as well. 
This it just for the Lucky Luke case, when you faster type as the blender engine can process it ; ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Monster's hint pointed me towards the real answer: Always look at the console window, when you are working with python. 
(HowTo is described here: https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/User:Fade/Doc:2.6/Manual/Interface/Window_system/Console_window .) When I was using the **Embedded Player** in the **Blender Game** **Properties Editor**, the console printed out that it not can "import bpy". 
So I realized that I only have to "import bge" and *not* have to "import bpy".

The second part to the answer I found in MikePan's answer in this post: 
[Packaging external libraries in the game engine 'Create Runtime'](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6606/packaging-external-libraries-in-the-game-engine-create-runtime). I work on a Mac and I simply had to copy the python file withe code for the controller into the `Content/MacOS/Resources` folder of the **Save As Game Engine Runtime** generated app.

This question and comments are as well related to the topic: [BGE: where to place external python modules when exporting for Mac OS X](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/63122/bge-where-to-place-external-python-modules-when-exporting-for-mac-os-x)

Comment: Always look at the console window, when you are working with python.

Comment: Thank you @Monster. As you can see in my edited answer, this was really helpful hint.